# Ошибка в создании бота для Discord на python

Tags: python, бот, discord-api, discord, discord.py

При запуске бота,

вот код:

```
import discord
import asyncio
import requests
import random
from dotenv import load_dotenv

DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN = '*************************'

# BTC_PRICE_URL_coinmarketcap = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/?convert=RUB'

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!!roll'):
        print('[command]: roll ')
        await client.send_message(message.channel, str(random.randint(0, 100)

client.run(DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN)
```

выдает ошибку:

```
File "discord-bot.py", line 28
    client.run(DISCORD_BOT_TOKEN)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Хоть вопрос и решён, но я вам не рекомендую хранить токен бота в самом скрипте. Храните его в отдельном файле, к примеру, token.txt

Answer (score 0):

Ты забыл закрыть `)`

```
    await client.send_message(message.channel, str(random.randint(0, 100)))
```

Comment: На самом деле, в этой строчке автор забыл закрыть ДВЕ скобки ))

Comment: Действительно! Ох уж эти скобочки